# Delete user's files in SharePoint via Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

My unattended DotNet Core app (C#) in Azure needs to use Graph API (Graph SDK) to delete a selected AD user's files from OneDrive & SharePoint with a particular file extension where the modified timestamp is at least 90 days ago.

For OneDrive then I get the list of user's drives and then get the relevant drive items. What do I need to do for SharePoint? I assumed that it would be one of the user's drives with driveType="documentLibrary" (i.e. Not "business" or "personal") but I don't find any drives.

Comment: Is this api what you want? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/listitem?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: How do I identify which site belongs to which user? I can see my own site when I get the site list (DisplayName=My name) but I was expecting to see my User Id set somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a SharePoint site does not belong to a specific user, it is just a site (that belongs to an organization). However, there is a SharePoint site that does belong to a user, and that is user's "OneDrive".

If you want to delete all files where a specific user is an owner (?), you may need to look through all files in the organization (i.e. on all SharePoint sites in the organization), find the ones where your user is an owner (or creator?) and delete those.

Comment: At the moment then I just need to process the user's SharePoint site. I can see my own site in the Graph API Sites list but I can't see how to programmatically identify it at runtime. I was expecting there to be a User Id property but Site.DisplayName (set to my name) seems to be the only way. But I assume that Site.DisplayName won't always match User.DisplayName for personal sites.